# Arduino DHCP failed to configure

Tags: arduino, ethernet, dhcp

I am using the example ethernet sketch for a web client that comes bundled with the Arduino software without changing a thing except for the firmware address, which I changed to the one printed on the back of the ethernet shield.

Whenever I connect the Arduino to my network and view the serial monitor, the only message I get is that it "Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP".

I have setup my Arduino Mega 2560 with an ethernet shield, correctly connecting ports 50 to MISO, 51 to MOSI, 52 to SCK, and 10 to SS (a.k.a. ETHCS as it is printed on the ethernet board).

Do you guys have any idea why this DHCP error would be happening?

Here is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {  0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x00, 0x73, 0xE4 }; //ethernet mac
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 9); //valid server IP in my network

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");

    for(;;)
      ;
  }

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");

    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }


  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it turns out (annoyingly), I had a faulty ethernet shield. New ethernet shield fixed the problem.

Comment: how did you know it is faulty?.. I am facing the same problem you have faced, but I can't determine if it is faulty or not..

Answer (score 3):

The solution that fixed this for me was to remove the Micro SD card from the slot, I saw your issue was related to a fault but others having this issue should remove the Micro SD card  after turning off the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After I removed the SD Card it worked for me the first time!

Comment: This question looks into the issue: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67045/ethernet-begin-only-works-with-sd-card-removed-why

Answer (score 1):

try this code :) it worked for me

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = {  
  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // this check is only needed on the Leonardo:


  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  // print your local IP address:
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print("."); 
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested that code yesterday.
My last resource... get rid of the "infinite" loop and back to static IP if DHCP fails.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give this code a try?

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO > 18
#include <SPI.h>
#endif
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetDHCP.h>

// MAC Address
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

const char* ip_to_str(const uint8_t*);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
Server server(8080);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Attempting to obtain a DHCP lease...");

  // Initiate a DHCP session. The argument is the MAC (hardware) address that
  // you want your Ethernet shield to use. This call will block until a DHCP
  // lease has been obtained. The request will be periodically resent until
  // a lease is granted, but if there is no DHCP server on the network or if
  // the server fails to respond, this call will block forever.
  // Thus, you can alternatively use polling mode to check whether a DHCP
  // lease has been obtained, so that you can react if the server does not
  // respond (see the PollingDHCP example).
  EthernetDHCP.begin(mac);

  // Since we're here, it means that we now have a DHCP lease, so we print
  // out some information.
  const byte* ipAddr = EthernetDHCP.ipAddress();
  const byte* gatewayAddr = EthernetDHCP.gatewayIpAddress();
  const byte* dnsAddr = EthernetDHCP.dnsIpAddress();

  Serial.println("A DHCP lease has been obtained.");

  Serial.print("My IP address is ");
  Serial.println(ip_to_str(ipAddr));

  Serial.print("Gateway IP address is ");
  Serial.println(ip_to_str(gatewayAddr));

  Serial.print("DNS IP address is ");
  Serial.println(ip_to_str(dnsAddr));

  // Start the server
   server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  // You should periodically call this method in your loop(): It will allow
  // the DHCP library to maintain your DHCP lease, which means that it will
  // periodically renew the lease and rebind if the lease cannot be renewed.
  // Thus, unless you call this somewhere in your loop, your DHCP lease might
  // expire, which you probably do not want :-)
  EthernetDHCP.maintain();

  // listen for incoming clients
  Client client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        // if you've gotten to the end of the line (received a newline
        // character) and the line is blank, the http request has ended,
        // so you can send a reply
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          // send a standard http response header
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
          client.println();

          // Some misc. HTML 
          client.println("<title>Arduino Control Panel</title>");
          client.println("<center><h1>Control Panel</h1></center>");
          client.println("<p></p>");

          // output the value of each analog input pin
          for (int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 6; analogChannel++) {
            client.print("Analog input ");
            client.print(analogChannel);
            client.print(" is ");
            client.print(analogRead(analogChannel));
            client.println("<br />");
          }
          break;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
  }
}

// Just a utility function to nicely format an IP address.
const char* ip_to_str(const uint8_t* ipAddr)
{
  static char buf[16];
  sprintf(buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d\0", ipAddr[0], ipAddr[1], ipAddr[2], ipAddr[3]);
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: That code more than 7 years old. I would suggest to try the official documentation at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DhcpAddressPrinter

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I discovered that the problem it generate with some types of switch because i have two (Encore Model ENH908-NWY Ver 3 and other IntelliNet Model 523301 Rev1).

With the switch Encore the DHCP presents problem, the Ethernet.begin(mac) return 0, but with IntelliNet the process DHCP works without problems.

I have a ADSL Huawei in my home which processes the DHCP requests.

I think that the problem it solve with a ethernet shield r3 but I have not tried that.

I post the code with it I try the DHCP requests.

When I try ethernet shield r3 I come here and tell you.

Greetings!

The property mac is previosly defined as array byte with six Hex.

```
void networkSetting(){
    byte stateNet = 0;

    //Se realiza petición DHCP para otros parámetros de Red si no están en memoria ya sea por System o Usuario
    if ((EEPROM.read(userConfig) != setted) && (EEPROM.read(systemConf) != setted)) {
        //Configurar el Socket solo con Mac
        if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0){
            Serial.println("DHCP not initialized! Try again...");
            return;
        }

        //Verificamos conexión
        stateNet = Ethernet.maintain();

        //Ponemos bandera de parámetros de Red System seteados si cumple alguna condición
        if (stateNet == 0 || stateNet == 2 || stateNet == 4)
        {
            //Obtenemos parámetros de Red
            getNetParams();
            //Guardamos parámetros de Red
            saveNetParams();
            //Seteamos configuración por Sistema
            EEPROM.write(systemConf, setted);
        } else {
            //Resetear Bandera de parámetros de System (Tomará DHCP en el próximo Reinicio)
            EEPROM.write(systemConf, 0);
        }
    } else {
        //cargar parámetros de red
        loadNetParams();

        //Configurar el Socket con los parámetros desde la memoria  
        Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, gateway, subnet);
    }

    //Iniciar el Servidor
    server.begin();

    //Se envían datos de estado de Red y Port a Puerto Serial
    Serial.println("Running as " + String(stateNet) + " in port " + String(port) + "!");
}
```

I attach captures of the two cases.

[The bad test with switch Encore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVWeq.png)

[The good test with switch IntelliNet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Azd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP. 
Ethernet.begin(mac) always returns 0.

Many people report the exact same problem.
It seems that you must connect to a router, not a switch.﻿

If not you have to make your PC as a server 
follow this link to know more--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xwwV_s9Gik